# visual studio 2017 console is not cmd anymore

Tags: console, visual-studio-2017

I have installed visual studio 2017 and run hello
world program. In the first time I installed visual studio 2017  the title of the output console 
was: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

Now the title is different it is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console.

How can I tell him to use the title 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

Of course it is not just the title that bothers me.
It seems that it call to a different program now. I would like it to call to C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
when presenting the output of a program, as before.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are doing? How did you create the 'hello world' program and how are you running it? Just by starting with F5?

Comment: I created an empty project, then for that project I went to properties and linker/system/subsystem and changed it to console. Then I added the source file by adding  a c++ program. I run the program with ctrl+F5. At the beginning of the program I wrote # include <iostream> and them using namespace std; and then cout<<"hello world"<<endl; I did all this before and the output was ok. now the output goes to a different window as mentioned above.